# python ncreduce for windows

Tags: c++, python, numpy

I'm doing astronomical image processing using python, and numpy.std(a) is consuming way too much memory. Some searching turns up the ncreduce package by Luis Pedro, but I'm having difficulty building my download of the package form [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ncreduce/0.2). [ActiveState](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/ncreduce/) seems to suggest that this package won't build on Windows.  I'm using Windows 7 and Python 2.7.

Is it possible to use ncreduce on Windows? If not, is there an alternative fast algorithm for computing standard deviation or variance that isn't as memory-hungry as numpy.std(a)?

Comment: Could you elaborate _'but I'm having difficulty building'_, that's quite hard to guess ...

Comment: Have you tried computing the mean of `a`, then computing the standard deviation explicitly using in-place operations?

Answer (score 3):

The package requires a few small changes to build with msvc. It is quite old and there are no tests so use at your own risk.

```
--- ncreduce/reduce.cpp Thu Aug 14 13:02:50 2008
+++ ncreduce/reduce.cpp Thu Sep 26 11:56:04 2013
@@ -6,6 +6,7 @@
 #include <iterator>
 #include <vector>
 #include <cmath>
+#include <limits>
 extern "C" {
     #include <Python.h>
     #include <numpy/ndarrayobject.h>
@@ -98,7 +99,7 @@
         }
         *result /= N;
         if (extra.is_std) {
-            *result = std::sqrt(*result);
+            *result = std::sqrt((double)(*result));
         }
     }

@@ -142,7 +143,7 @@
         for (unsigned i = 0; i != result.diameter(); ++i) {
             first_result[i] = divide(first_result[i],ArrSize/result.diameter());
             if (extra.is_std) {
-                first_result[i] = sqrt(first_result[i]);
+                first_result[i] = sqrt((double)first_result[i]);
             }
         }

--- setup.py    Thu Aug 14 13:54:48 2008
+++ setup.py    Thu Sep 26 12:03:16 2013
@@ -1,7 +1,7 @@
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
 from numpy.distutils.core import setup, Extension

-ncreduce = Extension('ncreduce', sources = ['ncreduce/reduce.cpp', 'ncreduce/numpy_utils.hpp'], extra_compile_args=['-Wno-sign-compare'])
+ncreduce = Extension('ncreduce', sources = ['ncreduce/reduce.cpp', 'ncreduce/numpy_utils.hpp'], extra_compile_args=['/EHsc'])

 classifiers = [
     'Development Status :: 4 - Beta',
```

I put the binaries at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ . Search for ncreduce.